# Tag Wiki Plagiarism

Tags: discussion, tags

There were a lot of tags in the last few days that plagiarized content from Wikipedia without correct attribution.

[rock-climbing](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rock-climbing)  [WP: Rock_Climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_Climbing)
[tendons](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tendons)       [WP: Tendons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tendons)
[ironman](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ironman)       [WP: Ironman_Triathlon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironman_Triathlon)
[ironman70.3](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ironman70.3)   [WP: Ironman_70.3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironman_70.3)
[skiing](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skiing)        [WP: Skiing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skiing)

I myself failed to see the plagiarism on some of those tags. I hate to see content copied without proper attribution and I don't think that we need to copy content from Wikipedia at all.
How should we treat already existing plagiarism?

Comment: Volleyball, calisthenics and bones tags are no more plagiarisms since my last edit. Saying sincere apology to the whole community by this comment. Didn't know this is an issue and I'll be watching for the playgiarism in tags too.

Comment: @tsykora No problem, this can happen to anyone not knowing. Copyright and licensing is quirky.

Comment: For Wikipedia: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79000/would-it-be-ok-to-paste-content-from-wikipedia-into-a-popular-empty-tag-wiki/79002#79002

Comment: @MattChan "as long as a link back to the original article is provided." there was no attribution in the copied content, thus it is plagiarized. Placing a (working) link in the excerpts isn't even possible.

Comment: I think if people or organizations allow to copy content based on CC licences, the least thing everyone should do is to attribute that stuff correctly (in fact that's the only thing you have to do).